# How to do conditional calculations in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, date-difference

I have a sample data that looks like this.

Column DateDuration was calculated in Excel, following below logic:

- DateDuration between SecondDate and FirstDate >= 28, then DateDuration = SecondDate - FirstDate.
- DateDuration between SecondDate and FirstDate <28, if ThirdDate = nan, then DateDuration = SecondDate - FirstDate.
- DateDuration between SecondDate and FirstDate <28, if ThirdDate = not nan, then consider (ThirdDate - FirstDate):

  - ThirdDate - FirstDate >= 28, then DateDuration = ThirdDate - FirstDate.
  - ThirdDate - FirstDate < 28, if FourthDate = nan, then DateDuration = ThirdDate - FirstDate.
  - ThirdDate - FirstDate < 28, if FourthDate = not nan, then DateDuration = FourthDate - FirstDate.

**I would like to calculate DateDuration in Python but do not know how to do about this.**

Types of data in Python:

- ID int64
- FirstDate  object
- SecondDate  object
- ThirdDate  object
- FourthDate  object

I am new to Python. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df['FirstDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FirstDate'])
df['SecondDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SecondDate'])
df['DayDifference2'] = (df['SecondDate']) -(df['FirstDate'])
df['DayDifference3'] = (df['ThirdDate']) -(df['FirstDate'])
df['DayDifference4'] = (df['FourthDate']) -(df['FirstDate'])
    
x = df['DayDifference2'].dt.days
y = df['DayDifference3'].dt.days
z = df['DayDifference4'].dt.days

condlist = [x<28, x>=28]
choicelist = [(df['ThirdDate']) -(df['FirstDate']), (df['SecondDate']) -(df['FirstDate'])]
np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

My data:

| ID | FirstDate | SecondDate | ThirdDate | FourthDate | DateDuration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2914300 | 2021-09-23 | 2021-10-07 | 2021-11-29 | 2021-12-20 | 67 |
| 3893461 | 2021-09-08 | 2021-10-06 | 2022-04-07 |  | 211 |
| 4343075 | 2021-06-23 | 2021-09-27 |  |  | 96 |
| 4347772 | 2021-06-23 | 2021-09-27 |  |  | 96 |
| 4551963 | 2021-08-02 | 2021-10-14 | 2022-03-11 |  | 73 |
| 4893324 | 2021-09-30 | 2021-10-01 | 2022-03-03 | 2022-03-10 | 154 |
| 5239991 | 2021-06-24 | 2021-08-26 | 2021-09-25 | 2022-02-03 | 63 |
| 8454947 | 2021-09-28 | 2021-10-05 |  |  | 7 |
| 8581390 | 2021-09-27 | 2022-03-21 | 2022-03-25 |  | 175 |
| 8763766 | 2021-09-20 | 2021-10-04 | 2021-12-09 |  | 80 |
| 9144185 | 2021-06-18 | 2021-06-23 |  |  | 5 |
| 9967685 | 2021-09-13 | 2021-10-29 | 2022-02-07 | 2022-03-23 | 46 |
| 11367560 | 2021-08-31 | 2021-09-28 | 2021-10-21 | 2022-02-11 | 51 |

Comment: Sorry I did try including my data as a table but it did not work. I had to put data in the code!!

Comment: Do `print(df)` and copy/paste the output.

Comment: I tried doing that but it did not work either. Thanks anw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('date_example.csv')
df.loc[:,'FirstDate':'FourthDate'] = df.loc[:,'FirstDate':'FourthDate'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df
```

[image]
`NaT` is a missing value of `datetime64[ns]` type

Conditions & Choices

```
conditions = [
    (df['SecondDate'] - df['FirstDate']).dt.days >= 28,
    ((df['SecondDate'] - df['FirstDate']).dt.days < 28) & df['ThirdDate'].isna(),
    ((df['SecondDate'] - df['FirstDate']).dt.days < 28) & df['ThirdDate'].notna() & ((df['ThirdDate'] - df['FirstDate']).dt.days >= 28),
    ((df['SecondDate'] - df['FirstDate']).dt.days < 28) & df['ThirdDate'].notna() & ((df['ThirdDate'] - df['FirstDate']).dt.days < 28) & df['FourthDate'].isna(),
    ((df['SecondDate'] - df['FirstDate']).dt.days < 28) & df['ThirdDate'].notna() & ((df['ThirdDate'] - df['FirstDate']).dt.days < 28) & df['FourthDate'].notna()
]

choices = [
    (df['SecondDate'] - df['FirstDate']).dt.days,
    (df['SecondDate'] - df['FirstDate']).dt.days,
    (df['ThirdDate'] - df['FirstDate']).dt.days,
    (df['ThirdDate'] - df['FirstDate']).dt.days,
    (df['FourthDate'] - df['FirstDate']).dt.days
]
```

```
df['Duration'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
df
```

Result
[image]

Discussion:
There are some differences, e.g., second row, `ID = 3893461`, according to your conditions(DateDuration between SecondDate and FirstDate >= 28, then DateDuration = SecondDate - FirstDate.), `SecondDate` - `FirstDate` of `ID = 3893461` is `28`, same thing happened on last row, `ID = 11367560`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. My result was based on DateDuration >28 or <=28.  Your code works perfectly. Thanks Baron!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the time module built-in. It allows for more time class types that I actually used for my own workout routine maker.

```
import datetime as dt

# particularly the types:
dt.timedelta(1)
# and
dt.time(minute=0, second=0)
# there are also date classes you can use.
```

Documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing this documentation!